# Request location coordinates after user has blocked access in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, geolocation, progressive-web-apps

How can I prompt a user for their geo-location in javascript if they've blocked my request in the past? (using [`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)).

For example,  my web app requires location services, and the user accidentally clicks "block", or they change their mind. What can I do to prompt them again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ask for geolocation permission again if it was denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678707/ask-for-geolocation-permission-again-if-it-was-denied)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As mentioned by @matthew-shwery, you can not change the permission.
the best you could do is check for the permission and notify the user is the permission is denied

```
navigator.permissions.query({
     name: 'geolocation'
 }).then(function(result) {
     if (result.state == 'granted') {
         report(result.state);
         geoBtn.style.display = 'none';
     } else if (result.state == 'prompt') {
         report(result.state);
         geoBtn.style.display = 'none';

         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(revealPosition, positionDenied, geoSettings);
     } else if (result.state == 'denied') {
         report(result.state);
         geoBtn.style.display = 'inline';
     }
     result.onchange = function() {
         report(result.state);
     }
 });
```

[Geolocation docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API)

Comment: On Chrome, you can direct them to their settings page:  `chrome://settings/content/location`.

Comment: how you do that? @ToolmakerSteve

Comment: @FernandoTorres - what I gave is a URL. What you do with it depends on your situation. You might put it in a link on your page, with some text explaining what this link is, and what to do when they get there.

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

The user must manage their browser settings manually because your site is added to a blacklist when denied location permissions.

Here are instructions for Chrome users to manage their location permissions: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en

Comment: On Chrome, you can direct them to their settings page:  `chrome://settings/content/location`.

Comment: I tried, can use window.open('chrome://settings/content/location"), gives error -> Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://settings/content/location