# How to re-ask permission to browser microphone?

Tags: javascript, browser, mediarecorder

How to re-ask permission to microphone in browsers?

My code is here:

```js
function askPermission() {
  var constraints = { audio: true, video: false };

  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(function(stream) {
      let audioContext = new AudioContext();
      console.log(audioContext);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

User needs to go to browser settings and allow it manually.

More info:
[ask for geolocation permission again if it was denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678707/ask-for-geolocation-permission-again-if-it-was-denied)